# Firebase database RecyclerView in a fragment causing Error in converting database to String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I implemented a `TabLayout` and I want to display my `Recyclerview` in one of the tabs so I created an adapter:

```
public class AdapterFrag extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView Longitude;
public TextView Latitude;
public TextView mName;
public RatingBar mRatingbar;
public ProperRatingBar mPriceBar;
public TextView mOperationHours;
public TextView nOperationHours;
public TextView mDescription;


public AdapterFrag(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_view);
            mRatingbar = (RatingBar) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.mstarRatingBar);
            mPriceBar = (ProperRatingBar) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.dollarsignratingbar);
            mOperationHours = (TextView) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursOfOperation_weekdays_firebase);
            nOperationHours = (TextView) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursOfOperation_weekends_firebase);
            mDescription = (TextView) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_firebase);

        }
}
```

And a model class with getters and setters and a constructor, and I made sure that the names in my database are the same with no funny business like uppercase difference.

```
public class RestaurantModel {
private static final String TAG ="KARAM" ;
private String name;
private String Description;
private String image;
private String RestaurantId;
private String rating;
private String Price;
private String mOperationHours;
private String Longitude;
private String Latitude;
private String nOperationHours;


public RestaurantModel() {
}


public RestaurantModel(String name, String description, String image, String 
restaurantId, String rating, String price, String mOperationHours, String 
longitude, String latitude, String nOperationHours) {
    this.name = name;
    Description = description;
    this.image = image;
    RestaurantId = restaurantId;
    this.rating = rating;
    Price = price;
    this.mOperationHours = mOperationHours;
    Longitude = longitude;
    Latitude = latitude;
    this.nOperationHours = nOperationHours;
}




public String getnOperationHours() {

    return nOperationHours;
}

public void setnOperationHours(String nOperationHours) {
    this.nOperationHours = nOperationHours;
}
public String getmOperationHours() {

    return mOperationHours;
}

public void setmOperationHours(String mOperationHours) {
    this.mOperationHours = mOperationHours;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return Longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    Longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return Latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    Latitude = latitude;
}


public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.Price = price;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.Description = description;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getRestaurantId() {
    return RestaurantId;
}

public void setRestaurantId(String restaurantId) {
    RestaurantId = restaurantId;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}
}
```

In my Main Activity holder activity, i implemented a Viewpagerclass to set fragment manager and the number of tabs like this

```
public class main_intermediate extends AppCompatActivity {


String uniqueId;
String Entname;
String mName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_intermediate);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.htab_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) 
findViewById(R.id.htab_viewpager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    if (getIntent() != null) {
        Intent intentres = getIntent();
        if (intentres.hasExtra("uniqueId")) {
            uniqueId = intentres.getStringExtra("uniqueId");

        } else if (getIntent() != null) {
            Intent intentbar = getIntent();
            if (intentbar.hasExtra("name")) {
                mName = intentbar.getStringExtra("name");
                if (!mName.isEmpty() && mName != null) {
                    loadBarAndClubDetails(mName);
                }

            } else if (getIntent() != null) {
                Intent intentent = getIntent();
                if (intentent.hasExtra("Entname")) {
                    Entname = intentent.getStringExtra("Entname");
                    if (!Entname.isEmpty() && Entname != null) {
                        loadEntertainmentdetails(mName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
   }

    private void loadBarAndClubDetails(String mName) {
    }

    private void loadEntertainmentdetails(String mName) {
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int mNumberOfTabs;

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumberOfTabs = NumOfTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("uniqueId", uniqueId);
                tab1.setArguments(bundle);

                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                 bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("uniqueId", uniqueId);
                tab2.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumberOfTabs;
    }
}
}
```

Finally, in my fragment i inflated the recyclerview in the xml file and i set a recyclerview 
and then i set the firebaserecycleradapter like this

```
public class TabFragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {
public TextView Longitude;
public TextView Latitude;
public TextView mName;
public RatingBar mRatingbar;
public ProperRatingBar mPriceBar;
public TextView mOperationHours;
public TextView nOperationHours;
public TextView mDescription;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
String resMid;
View mV;
GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseReference mRestaurantId;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String TAG = "Karam";


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRestaurantId = database.getReference("Restaurant");

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        resMid = getArguments().getString("uniqueId");
        Log.d(TAG, "everything is safe till here :)" + resMid);

    } else { Log.d(TAG, "getArguments is null");}
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_fragment_1, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mRestaurantId = mRestaurantId.child(resMid);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RestaurantModel,AdapterFrag> adapter = new 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RestaurantModel, AdapterFrag>(
            RestaurantModel.class,
            R.layout.tab_fragment_1,
            AdapterFrag.class,
            mRestaurantId
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(AdapterFrag viewHolder, 
RestaurantModel model, int position) {

            mDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
            mPriceBar.setRating(Integer.parseInt(model.getPrice()));
            mRatingbar.setRating(Integer.parseInt(model.getRating()));
            mName.setText(model.getName());
            mOperationHours.setText(model.getmOperationHours());
            nOperationHours.setText(model.getnOperationHours());
        }
    };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}





}
```

but it is not populating and it is giving me an error  like this:

```
07-22 18:27:20.451 20797-20797/com.example.karam.nlcg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.karam.nlcg, PID: 20797
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type 
java.lang.String to type com.example.karam.nlcg.Restaurant.RestaurantModel
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_
database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:259)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.
firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.
onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.
bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at 
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.
tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
```

I read on github it could be a library problem but i dont think so, i think i am missing something but i really cannot know what it is?

if you can explain why i can fix it i just need to know!

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can u post the database structure.

Comment: sure, the data structure is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.karam.nlcg.Restaurant.RestaurantModel
```

Because your `mRestaurantId` object points to a reference of type String and not of type `RestaurantModel`. This is happening because you are first initialize it as:

```
mRestaurantId = database.getReference("Restaurant");
```

And later you are changing it to:

```
mRestaurantId = mRestaurantId.child(resMid);
```

Which obviously is pointing to the a reference of type String. To solve this, just comment/remove this line of code and use only the first one.

Comment: thank you for clarification, now i understand why, but i need to access the node that is refrenced by resMid

Comment: You're welcome! So access it but do not pass that reference to the adaper, right?

Answer (score 0):

See your firebase structure has an attribute menu but your model (`RestaurantModel`) does not have that attribute.

`RestaurantModel` has only attributes of String type.

So answer to your question is modify your `RestaurantModel`.

**UPDATED**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRestaurantId = database.getReference("Restaurant");


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_fragment_1, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RestaurantModel,AdapterFrag> adapter = new 
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RestaurantModel, AdapterFrag>(
            RestaurantModel.class,
            R.layout.tab_fragment_1,
            AdapterFrag.class,
            mRestaurantId
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this will solve your problem. So mark this answer as accepted. So that it can be useful for others too.

Comment: This is a wrong answer, sorry. i deleted my menu attribute and i deleted it from the restaurant model and it is still displaying the same error.

Comment: Update your database structure.@KaramJaber

Comment: i did man, i deleted my menu attribute from firebase database

Comment: Plz post the new database structure @KaramJaber

Comment: I just did, new Data Structure posted

Comment: Plz refer the updated code. Modify your code in such way. It will solve your problem.

Comment: You literally deleted my database reference for the clicked item, if i do that it will show all the nodes under "Restaurant", so sorry again wrong.